# Is there a word that describes a word that makes you feel the thing you are describing as you say it?

Tags: single-word-requests

Sort of like onomatopoeia, where the word sounds like that which it describes, but where saying the word makes one feel like that which it describes.

Sorry for the terrible explanation.

EDIT: This came up during a conversation with a friend who described something as 'scuzzy'. Saying scuzzy makes me feel scuzzy and here we are...

Comment: Can you provide an example sentence?

Comment: I can think of words where the *circumstances* or *manner* in which they're said could make you feel like their meaning - shouting "EMBARRASSED!" in a quiet theatre would do it, or certain profanities said in polite company. Is that what you mean? I can't think of any examples where a word will *always* have that effect, wherever it is said.

Comment: Seems like a big ask!  Perhaps in German ...?

Comment: Real life example given...

Comment: I think I know exactly what you have in mind. In the U.S. it is impossible to use the word _corny_ without feeling as though you just walked into a sophisticated soiree in your overalls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Ideophone**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideophone)

> 'A vivid representation of an idea in sound. A word, often
>   onomatopoeic, which describes a predicate, qualificative or adverb in
>   respect to manner, color, sound, smell, action, state or intensity.’
>
> Ideophones evoke sensory events.

Example: "**twinkle**: the glow of something sparkling or shiny."

We say, *her eyes twinkled merrily* or we say *wow!* and our mere saying it makes us express admiration or surprise.

Comment: Nice word.  Does *...saying the word makes one feel like that which it describes*?

Answer (score 0):

This is subjective, but I submit the word "Cacophonous", which describes anything that involves or produces a harsh or discordant mixture of sounds.

EDIT: It seems like you were looking for something more general. Per one of the other posts, "cacophony" is but one example of "ideophone".

Answer (score 0):

> Mood: In literature, mood is a literary element that evokes certain feelings or vibes in readers through words and descriptions. Usually, mood is referred to as the atmosphere of a literary piece, as it creates an emotional setting that surrounds the readers.
>   <sub>[Literary Devices: Mood](https://literarydevices.net/mood/)</sub>

Comment: Hi Terry, welcome to EL&U. This is on the way to being a good answer, but note that our site is a bit different from other Q&A sites: an answer here is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct* - preferably by quoting a reference (e.g. a dictionary definition) hyperlinked to the source. You can [edit] your post to add this detail; for further guidance, see [answer]. Make sure you also take the EL&U **[Tour]** :-)